# How to create docker image using already configured application folder

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

My basic requirement is to create docker image and deploy it to docker registry.

I have a pre-configured application folder(/home/myfolder) in my jenkins server(to do this configuration I have used ansible script). Then I need to create docker image from that folder and deploy it to docker registry.

What's the best way to do this? Please help me with this as I'm new to  docker.

please find my Dockerfile below

```
  #Download base image ubuntu 16.04
  FROM ubuntu

  WORKDIR /dockerprojects



  #copy the zip file to docker folder
  COPY /wso2telcohub-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT /home/myfolder/dockerprojects/IGW/dockerCI

  COPY cp /wso2is-km-5.6.0 /home/myfolder/dockerprojects/IGW/dockerCI

  CMD [“bash”]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please help us with a few more details - otherwise the answer will have to make a lot of assumptions. Do you have a Dockerfile that defines what will be in the image already? If so, can you share it here? Do you want to perform the operation from Jenkins? From a pipeline or perhaps a freetyle project?

Comment: Also, what registry do you want to push it to? Docker hub? Or a private registry?

Comment: I added my Dockerfile to the question. may be it's wrong. please correct me if i'm wrong & i need to push it to docker hub

Comment: If you can explain what files it exactly is that you want to copy in the image, and where they are located on the host machine, then I think I can help you solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things in that Dockerfile that potentially can go sideways. I will comment on them one by one here:

```
#Download base image ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu
```

If you intend to use the `ubuntu:16.04` image, you need to specify it. Without a specific tag, the `FROM` instruction will look for the `latest` tag, in this case the find the image `ubuntu:latest` for you.

```
WORKDIR /dockerprojects
```

This command sets the workdir inside the docker image, so that when the container starts, the sessions `PWD` will be set to `/dockerprojects`. This is important because all other commands durring the build and when the container is started will be relative to this location in the file structure.

```
#copy the zip file to docker folder
COPY /wso2telcohub-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT /home/myfolder/dockerprojects/IGW/dockerCI
```

This command will copy the file `/wso2telcohub-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT` from the "host machine", the machine where the docker image is being built, into the image at the location `/home/myfolder/dockerprojects/IGW/dockerCI`. If the location does not already exist in the image, then it will create a file named `dockerCI` at the location `/home/myfolder/dockerprojects/IGW/`. I don't think that this is what you want.

Also, your comment states that this is a zip file, but it seems to be missing an extension like `.zip` or `.gz` - I believe that you are not referencing the file correctly.

```
COPY cp /wso2is-km-5.6.0 /home/myfolder/dockerprojects/IGW/dockerCI
```

This instruction will not execute. For the COPY instruction you don't need to use a "cp" command. If you removed "cp" from the line however, it would try to copy the file or directory `/wso2is-km-5.6.0` from the host machine (that's a file in the root of the filesystem) to the location `/home/myfolder/dockerprojects/IGW/dockerCI` inside the resulting image.

```
CMD [“bash”]
```

The CMD instruction simply sets the image to start a new bash shell when started - which will make the container exit immediatly when the `bash` command completes.

I have a feeling that the source location of the files that you want to put in the image is not in the root of the host machine. But probably at `/home/myfolder/dockerprojects/` on the host that you mention. I have asked you to clearify the location of the files that you want in the image in a comment on your question.

Update

The error that you are getting 'no such file or directory' means that the source file that you are referencing in the `COPY` instruction, does not exist.

The `COPY` instruction works like this:

```
COPY <sourcepath> <targetpath>
```

Where the `<sourcepath>` is the path of the file on the machine where the image is being built. This path is relative to the Dockerfile (or the build context if specified), unless it starts with a `/`, then it is relative to the root of the filesystem on the host machine. And the `targetpath` is the desired path inside the resulting image.

Let's say that I have the following folder structure:

```
/home/myfolder/dockerprojects/
├── Dockerfile
├── wso2telcohub-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
├── wso2is-km-5.6.0/
│   ├── anotherfile.txt
```

And I wanted all the files in the path `/home/myfolder/dockerprojects/` to be put inside the docker image, below the path `/app`. I would do this with a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app/
```

Or each file individually like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./wso2telcohub-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip /app/wso2telcohub-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
COPY ./wso2is-km-5.6.0 /app/wso2is-km-5.6.0
```

That would leave me with the following in the docker image:

```
/app/
├── Dockerfile
├── wso2telcohub-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
├── wso2is-km-5.6.0/
│   ├── anotherfile.txt
```

Comment: i have corrected the copy as  COPY /wso2telcohub-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip /home/myfolder/dockerprojects/IGW/dockerCI . but it gives error as 'no such file or directory'. what might be the reason for that ?

Comment: also i have tried by giving exact path as well. it also didn't work well